# Bullet points appear as a 't' when exporting PDFs from WPS Office

Tags: libreoffice, fonts, pdf, wps-office

When I export a presentation to PDF from WPS Office, I have the issue that bullet points do not show correctly. In WPS office the bullet points being shown like this:

[image: bullet points in WPS office]

In the exported PDF they look like this:

[image: bullet points in PDF]

This is the case, when opening the PDF in `Okular` and `Evince`. It does *not* when using `acroread` to open the PDF.

I suspect that this is could be due to missing fonts, but I do not know how to fix this (or even which Font I would have to get, because this happens also for different fonts).

Also, I saw that Microsoft Office has the ability to embed fonts in the PDF on export (which might fix tihs), but I was unable to find this option in WPS office.

Comment: How does this relate to Ubuntu?

Comment: @David good question: I guess, because I am using ubuntu and I suspect that it has to do with the fonts that are installed.